# Updating a datagridview from a button in other form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I have to forms, form1 and form2.

In form1 I have a datagridview that loads the data from my database, two buttons, one for a filter and another to add a row to the datagridview.

In form2 I have some comboboxes, textboxes, radiobuttons, and four buttons, one that adds the data, one to remove the selected row(when I double clic a row in the datagridview the form2 is loaded with that info from that row), one to cancel(close the form), and the last one is to update the selected row with the modified info.

But my problem is that I'm stucked there, I don't know how to update the same row. I'm able to add a new one or erase one. I'm working on C# with Entity Framework.

May someone help me on how to update the selected row from another form?

I tried modifying the code that I use when I double clic the datagridview to load the data in form2:

```
Inspeccion inspeccio = new Inspeccion();
inspeccio.ID =Int32.Parse(txtNumTransaccion.Text);
inspeccio.Vehiculo = Int32.Parse(cbxIdVehiculo.Text);
inspeccio.Cliente= Int32.Parse(cbxIdCliente.Text);
inspeccio.Ralladuras = ralladuras().ToString();
inspeccio.Cantidad_Combustible = cbxCombustible.Text.ToString();
inspeccio.Repuesta = repuesta().ToString();
inspeccio.Gato = gato().ToString();
inspeccio.Cristal = cristal().ToString();
inspeccio.Fecha_Inspeccion = DateTime.Parse(fecha.Text);
inspeccio.Empleado_Inspeccion = Int32.Parse(cbxIdEmpleado.Text);
inspeccio.Estado = cbxEstVehiculo.Text.ToString();
MessageBox.Show("Se ha actualizado con exito.");
```

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: I tried modifying the code that I use when I double clic the datagridview to load the data in form2, I posted my try.

Answer (score 0):

Use some static variables to store row information when you go to form2. on returning, use those static variables to update the same row.
Example:

```
public static int rowId;
public static bool changed = false;
private void rowClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//get row id. say you got row id = 1
Form1.rowId = 1;
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.ShowDialog();
if(Form1.changed)
updateRowinGridView(rowId);
}
```

In the Form2 button, use the following code sample:

```
private void updateButton(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
//Update Record//
Form1.changed = true;
Close();
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement one DataSet in around of your project, when you update it, all of your binding components are refreshed.